# Installing Citrix receiver on 64bit Debian Wheezy

Tags: apt, debian, citrix

I am trying to install [Citrix receiver v. 13](http://www.citrix.com/downloads/citrix-receiver/linux/receiver-for-linux-130.html) on my 64 bit Debian Wheezy. I tried both amd64 as well as i386 packages (in multiarch), but I fail.

**i386 version first**

```
The installation looks like this:
root@grzes:/home/ga/Downloads# dpkg -i icaclient_13.0.0.256735_i386.deb 
Selecting previously unselected package icaclient.
(Reading database ... 338506 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking icaclient (from icaclient_13.0.0.256735_i386.deb) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of icaclient:
 icaclient depends on libxmu6.
 icaclient depends on libxerces-c3.1.
 icaclient depends on libcurl3 (>= 7.19.1).
 icaclient depends on libwebkit-1.0-2 | libwebkitgtk-1.0-0.

dpkg: error processing icaclient (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for gnome-menus ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils ...
Processing triggers for menu ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 icaclient
```

When I try to fix the problem, I get:

```
root@grzes:/home/ga/Downloads# apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  glib-networking:i386 libcurl3:i386 libdbus-glib-1-2:i386 libgail18:i386 libhunspell-1.3-0:i386 libproxy0:i386 librtmp0:i386 libsoup2.4-1:i386 libssh2-1:i386 libxerces-c3.1:i386 libxmu6:i386
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libcurl3:i386 libicu48:i386 librtmp0:i386 libssh2-1:i386 libxerces-c3.1:i386 libxmu6:i386
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  enchant icaclient:i386
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libcurl3:i386 libicu48:i386 librtmp0:i386 libssh2-1:i386 libxerces-c3.1:i386 libxmu6:i386
0 upgraded, 6 newly installed, 2 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 6,560 kB of archives.
After this operation, 3,090 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]?
```

Basically it is trying to fix the problem by removing the package I am trying to install. Now this might explain a bit why:

```
root@grzes:/home/ga/Downloads# apt-get install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 icaclient:i386 : Depends: libxmu6:i386 but it is not installed
                  Depends: libxerces-c3.1:i386 but it is not installed
                  Depends: libcurl3:i386 (>= 7.19.1) but it is not installed
                  Depends: libwebkit-1.0-2:i386 but it is not installable or
                           libwebkitgtk-1.0-0:i386 but it is not installed
                  Recommends: hptc-ica-support:i386 but it is not installable
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

**amd64 version**

```
root@grzes:/home/ga/Downloads# dpkg -i icaclient_13.0.0.256735_amd64.deb 
Selecting previously unselected package icaclient.
(Reading database ... 338506 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking icaclient (from icaclient_13.0.0.256735_amd64.deb) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of icaclient:
 icaclient depends on libc6-i386 (>= 2.7-1); however:
  Package libc6-i386 is not installed.
 icaclient depends on ia32-libs; however:
  Package ia32-libs is not installed.
 icaclient depends on lib32z1; however:
  Package lib32z1 is not installed.
 icaclient depends on lib32asound2; however:
  Package lib32asound2 is not installed.
 icaclient depends on nspluginwrapper; however:
  Package nspluginwrapper is not installed.

dpkg: error processing icaclient (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for gnome-menus ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils ...
Processing triggers for menu ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 icaclient
root@grzes:/home/ga/Downloads# apt-get install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 icaclient : Depends: libc6-i386 (>= 2.7-1) but it is not installed
             Depends: ia32-libs but it is not installed
             Depends: lib32z1 but it is not installed
             Depends: lib32asound2 but it is not installed
             Depends: nspluginwrapper but it is not installable
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
root@grzes:/home/ga/Downloads# apt-get install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  ia32-libs lib32asound2 lib32z1 libc6-i386
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  freeglut3:i386 ia32-libs ia32-libs-i386:i386 lesstif2:i386 lib32asound2 lib32z1 libacl1:i386 libaio1:i386 libaudiofile1:i386 libbsd0:i386 libc6-i386 libcaca0:i386 libcurl3:i386 libdirectfb-1.2-9:i386 libedit2:i386 libesd0:i386
  libfltk1.1:i386 libgdbm3:i386 libjpeg62:i386 liblzo2-2:i386 libncursesw5:i386 libnspr4:i386 libnspr4-0d:i386 libnss3:i386 libnss3-1d:i386 libpam0g:i386 libpopt0:i386 librtmp0:i386 libsdl1.2debian:i386 libsigc++-2.0-0c2a:i386
  libslang2:i386 libssh2-1:i386 libstdc++5:i386 libsvga1:i386 libsysfs2:i386 libtdb1:i386 libts-0.0-0:i386 libvorbisfile3:i386 libx86-1:i386 libxaw7:i386 libxcb-render-util0:i386 libxmu6:i386 libxmuu1:i386 libxp6:i386
  odbcinst1debian2:i386 xaw3dg:i386
Suggested packages:
  ia32-libs-gtk ia32-libs-gtk-i386:i386 pulseaudio-esound-compat:i386 libpam-doc:i386
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  icaclient
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  freeglut3:i386 ia32-libs ia32-libs-i386:i386 lesstif2:i386 lib32asound2 lib32z1 libacl1:i386 libaio1:i386 libaudiofile1:i386 libbsd0:i386 libc6-i386 libcaca0:i386 libcurl3:i386 libdirectfb-1.2-9:i386 libedit2:i386 libesd0:i386
  libfltk1.1:i386 libgdbm3:i386 libjpeg62:i386 liblzo2-2:i386 libncursesw5:i386 libnspr4:i386 libnspr4-0d:i386 libnss3:i386 libnss3-1d:i386 libpam0g:i386 libpopt0:i386 librtmp0:i386 libsdl1.2debian:i386 libsigc++-2.0-0c2a:i386
  libslang2:i386 libssh2-1:i386 libstdc++5:i386 libsvga1:i386 libsysfs2:i386 libtdb1:i386 libts-0.0-0:i386 libvorbisfile3:i386 libx86-1:i386 libxaw7:i386 libxcb-render-util0:i386 libxmu6:i386 libxmuu1:i386 libxp6:i386
  odbcinst1debian2:i386 xaw3dg:i386
0 upgraded, 46 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 12.5 MB of archives.
After this operation, 5,949 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]?
```

**QUESTION:**
How can I install one of these two versions? In the first case I need to install `libwebkit-1.0-2:i386` but it seems to conflict with the amd64 version, and in the latter I need `nspluginwrapper` but it is not in the repositories for some reason.

Comment: `nspluginwrapper` is in the repos, but you need to enable `contrib`. See: https://wiki.debian.org/DebianSoftware#Non-Free_Software_.28e.g._Adobe.27s_Flash.29

Comment: @jordanm, it was in Squeeze, but it is not anymore now...

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me and someone else who had this problem, so I documented it and share it with you.
This was tested with Debian 7.4. It may work on older versions of Debian as well, but I have not tested this.

Get the citrix .deb: http://www.citrix.com/downloads/citrix-receiver/linux/
*Select the 64-bit .deb installer.*

Example filename: `icaclient_13.0.0.256735_amd64.deb`

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386

sudo apt-get install ia32-libs ia32-libs-i386 libglib2.0-0:i386 libgtk2.0-0:i386

sudo dpkg --force-all --install icaclient_13.0.0.256735_amd64.deb

sudo cp --verbose /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/* /opt/citrix/icaclient/keystcacerts/
```

Now try to run a citrix / ica connection.
You may to point your browser to wfica in `/opt/Citrix/Icaclient/` at the first time.

The following may seem strange, but you are *forced* to delete `Icaclient` in order to install the software with apt-get.

```
cd /opt/Citrix/

sudo cp Icaclient ~/

sudo apt-get -f install
```

This will delete ica client.
Don't worry, just do it.

```
cd ~/

sudo mv Icaclient /opt/Citrix/
```

Try to run a citrix session as before.

I tested this with iceweasel, I am positive it will work for firefox as well, but I don't know if it works with chrome or any other browser...

Comment: `ia32-libs` etc. is obsolete for wheezy. You should install the library you actually need. Also, using the dpkg `--force-all` flag is not a great idea. What error do you get without it?

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu 16.04 and just ran the first and third line (second line encountered the obsolete error). The `--force-all` flag seems to have fixed my problem, although I have absolutely no idea what damage I may have done to my system :)) Either way, it's working for ICA provided by my school (NYU).

Answer (score 0):

I ran the following;

`sudo apt update`

`sudo apt upgrade` - this identified the missing libraries

`sudo apt --fix-broken install` - this installed the missing libraries

Answer (score -2):

Run:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

then install the deb file, will solve the problem. I have tried.